# JavaScript Websocket catch onerror

Tags: javascript, websocket, onerror

Is it possible to catch the browser error when

```
socket = new WebSocket(WSHost);
```

fails and try .. catch doesn't work?

Check this jsfiddle and open browser console  (F12) and click connect:

http://jsfiddle.net/gsz4kpw4/15/

the  "socket.onerror"  fires, but there is no error message inside the error event. The browser is logging the message to it's console. Any one know a possibility to catch this message and output with alert?

I also tried this:

```
    function yourCustomLog(msg) {
       alert(msg);
    }

    window.console= yourCustomLog;
```

But it seems that the browser websocket connect error isn't a real console error. There is no alert when the error occurs.

Comment: Think the error is being dealt with and passed to the onerror internally.